# Is there a memory leak inside CLIPSCRLWrapper.dll of clips6.40 to integrate C#?

Tags: clips

I'm trying to use CLIPSCRLWrapper.dll of clips6.40 to integrate C#. I can input 200 facts per second and output the conclusion correctly. But there is a problem that bothers me. As the running time of the program increases, the memory consumption increases at the rate of 1M per minute. My program is very simple. I initialize clips net in C #

```
Environment clips = new CLIPSNET.Environment();
clips.Load("test.clp");
```

The timer is used to activate every 1 second

```
clips.Reset(); 
clips.AssertString("(attribute (name Dev001) (status ACT01))");
clips.AssertString("(attribute (name Dev002) (status BOT06))");
clips.AssertString("(attribute (name Dev003) (status GCC09))"); 
... ... 
clips.AssertString("(attribute (name Dev200) (status TTL12))"); 
clips.Run();
```

Does factstring free memory every time clips.Reset() is called? Is there a memory leak inside CLIPSCRLWrapper.dll of clips6.40?
What can I do to free memory after each clips.Run()?

Thank you!

**@Gary ,Here are two times the memory heap information fetched by WinDbg.Can you give me some advice?
Thank you in advance!**

*memory heap information fetched by WinDbg*

```
0:010> !heap -s
NtGlobalFlag enables following debugging aids for new heaps:
stack back traces
LFH Key                   : 0x22f1bb37
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
03b60000 08000002   16472  15456  16364   1547   347     6    0     1a   LFH     <---------------------
02930000 08001002     168     64     60     21     6     1    0      0   LFH
03fd0000 08001002    1188    704   1080    339    41     2    0      2   LFH
05840000 08001002    1188    152   1080     16     6     2    0      0   LFH
05930000 08041002      60      4     60      2     1     1    0      0      
07fa0000 08001002    1188     88   1080     16    17     2    0      0   LFH
08140000 08041002    1188    100   1080      5     3     2    0      0   LFH
080f0000 08001002      60     20     60      9     2     1    0      0      
08200000 08001002    1188    176   1080     27    13     2    0      0   LFH
13370000 08001002    1188    140   1080     20    14     2    1      0   LFH
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0:007> !heap -s

NtGlobalFlag enables following debugging aids for new heaps:
stack back traces
LFH Key                   : 0x22f1bb37
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
03b60000 08000002   32660  25040  32552   1892   357     7    1     1a   LFH     <---------------------
02930000 08001002     168     64     60     21     6     1    0      0   LFH
03fd0000 08001002    1188    704   1080    339    41     2    0      2   LFH
05840000 08001002    1188    152   1080     16     6     2    0      0   LFH
05930000 08041002      60      4     60      2     1     1    0      0      
07fa0000 08001002    1188     88   1080     16    17     2    0      0   LFH
08140000 08041002    1188    100   1080      5     3     2    0      0   LFH
080f0000 08001002      60     20     60      9     2     1    0      0      
08200000 08001002    1188    176   1080     27    13     2    0      0   LFH
13370000 08001002    1188    140   1080     20    14     2    1      0   LFH
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*There's a lot of memory(size is "2c") that hasn't been reclaimed.*

```
0:007> !heap -stat -h 03b60000
 heap @ 03b60000
group-by: TOTSIZE max-display: 20
size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
2c 15bba - 3bc3f8  (36.04)     <---------------------
1148 1f0 - 217b80  (20.19)
cff 20f - 1ac0f1  (16.13)
a9e40 1 - a9e40  (6.40)
800 4f - 27800  (1.49)
25d40 1 - 25d40  (1.43)
480 70 - 1f800  (1.19)
79e8 3 - 16db8  (0.86)
20 b36 - 166c0  (0.85)
2000 a - 14000  (0.75)
24 5dc - d2f0  (0.50)
d0 e4 - b940  (0.44)
364 31 - a624  (0.39)
64 1a9 - a604  (0.39)
330 2a - 85e0  (0.32)
8000 1 - 8000  (0.30)
4000 2 - 8000  (0.30)
1000 8 - 8000  (0.30)
114 72 - 7ae8  (0.29)
a8 b0 - 7380  (0.27)

0:007> !heap -flt s 2c
_HEAP @ 3b60000
  HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
    03b65e98 0009 0000  [00]   03b65eb0    0002c - (busy)
    03b65fa0 0009 0009  [00]   03b65fb8    0002c - (busy)
    03b663a8 0009 0009  [00]   03b663c0    0002c - (busy)
    03b665f0 0009 0009  [00]   03b66608    0002c - (busy)
    03b669c0 0009 0009  [00]   03b669d8    0002c - (busy)
    03b6a570 0009 0009  [00]   03b6a588    0002c - (busy)
    03b74548 0009 0009  [00]   03b74560    0002c - (busy)
    03b74818 0009 0009  [00]   03b74830    0002c - (busy)
    03b74ae0 0009 0009  [00]   03b74af8    0002c - (busy)
    03b750a0 0009 0009  [00]   03b750b8    0002c - (busy)
    03b76ca0 0009 0009  [00]   03b76cb8    0002c - (busy)
    03b76ce8 0009 0009  [00]   03b76d00    0002c - (busy)
    03b76dc0 0009 0009  [00]   03b76dd8    0002c - (busy)
    03b76e08 0009 0009  [00]   03b76e20    0002c - (busy)
    03b76e50 0009 0009  [00]   03b76e68    0002c - (busy)
    03b76e98 0009 0009  [00]   03b76eb0    0002c - (busy)
    03b76f28 0009 0009  [00]   03b76f40    0002c - (busy)
      kernel_appcore!_load_config_used <PERF> (kernel_appcore+0x0)
    03b77090 0009 0009  [00]   03b770a8    0002c - (busy)
    03b770d8 0009 0009  [00]   03b770f0    0002c - (busy)
      unknown!printable
    03b77120 0009 0009  [00]   03b77138    0002c - (busy)
    03b77168 0009 0009  [00]   03b77180    0002c - (busy)
    ...
    16931d60 0009 0009  [00]   16931d78    0002c - (busy)
    16931ec8 0009 0009  [00]   16931ee0    0002c - (busy)     <---------------------
    16931f10 0009 0009  [00]   16931f28    0002c - (busy)     <---------------------
_HEAP @ 2930000
_HEAP @ 3fd0000
    08321b68 0009 0009  [00]   08321b80    0002c - (busy)
_HEAP @ 5840000
_HEAP @ 5930000
_HEAP @ 7fa0000
_HEAP @ 8140000
_HEAP @ 80f0000
_HEAP @ 8200000
_HEAP @ 13370000
    13372b38 0009 0009  [00]   13372b50    0002c - (busy)
      unknown!printable
```

*Any two fragment addresses*

```
0:007> !heap -p -a 16931f28
address 16931f28 found in
_HEAP @ 3b60000
  HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
    16931f10 0009 0000  [00]   16931f28    0002c - (busy)
    771978a4 ntdll!RtlpCallInterceptRoutine+0x00000026
    77106e7c ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal+0x0000108c
    77105dde ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x0000003e
    153eb5f5 ucrtbased!heap_alloc_dbg_internal+0x00000195
    153eb416 ucrtbased!heap_alloc_dbg+0x00000036
    153edb8a ucrtbased!_malloc_dbg+0x0000001a
    153ee4a4 ucrtbased!malloc+0x00000014
    122cecfd CLIPSCLRWrapper+0x000aecfd     <---------------------


0:007> !heap -p -a 16931ee0
address 16931ee0 found in
_HEAP @ 3b60000
  HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
    16931ec8 0009 0000  [00]   16931ee0    0002c - (busy)
    771978a4 ntdll!RtlpCallInterceptRoutine+0x00000026
    77106e7c ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal+0x0000108c
    77105dde ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x0000003e
    153eb5f5 ucrtbased!heap_alloc_dbg_internal+0x00000195
    153eb416 ucrtbased!heap_alloc_dbg+0x00000036
    153edb8a ucrtbased!_malloc_dbg+0x0000001a
    153ee4a4 ucrtbased!malloc+0x00000014
    122cecfd CLIPSCLRWrapper+0x000aecfd     <---------------------
```

Comment: How are you measuring memory use?

Comment: Thank you so much, Gary!  I try to use two ways: 
 1.Check the memory usage of the application every 2 minutes through the task manager of windows, and the memory keeps increasing.  
 2. Through the analysis of Microsoft's WinDbg debugging tool, the application memory usage .Looking at the memory heap every two minutes, it's growing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a leak. I fixed this in April but apparently forgot to check in the fix. There's some bridge code between C# and C++ with a circular dependency which prevents the C# garbage collector from reclaiming some of the deallocated memory. Since the objects with the circular dependency are paired and deleted at the same time, I modified the C++ object to have a weak reference to the C# object and this resolves the issue. You can download the changes for commit r809 at https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/.

Here's a small example demonstrating how to check for a memory leak within your code. Calling GetTotalMemory with the value true forces the garbage collector to release deallocated memory so you can more easily determine if there is a memory leak.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using CLIPSNET;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long totalMemory;
            var rand = new Random();

            CLIPSNET.Environment clips = new CLIPSNET.Environment();

            clips.Build("(defrule sort ?f <- (numbers $?b ?x ?y&:(> ?x ?y) $?e) => (retract ?f) (assert (numbers ?b ?y ?x ?e)))");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                { 
                    clips.Reset();
                    clips.AssertString("(numbers " + rand.Next() + " " + rand.Next() + " " +
                                                     rand.Next() + " " + rand.Next() + " " +
                                                     rand.Next() + " " + rand.Next() + ")");
                    clips.Run();
                }
                
                totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
                Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + totalMemory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```